# TinyMCE max width of table

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE in a Vue application.

I have configured TinyMCE with `table_grid: false` which has the effect that a dialog is opened when a table is created. In the dialog you can specify rows, column, width etc. In this dialog I want to set max allowed width of the table. I want to restrict max width to 100%. As it works now it is possible to set the width greather than 100% which results in a table with a width bigger than `<TinyMCEEditor>`.

I have managed to change to size of the table using css. But the best solution would be if the user was not able to enter a width greater than 100%.

Comment: I can't get the image to show. :(

Comment: are you using tinymce-vue(https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue)?

Comment: @OlieCape Yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following options

Use CSS for Default Behavior

```
tinymce.init({
    // other settings...
    content_style: "table {width: 100% !important; max-width: 100% !important;}"
});
```

Validation on Table Property Changes :

```
tinymce.init({
    // other settings...
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
            if (e.command === 'mceInsertTable' || e.command === 'mceTableProps') {
                // Delay the check to ensure it runs after the table is inserted/updated
                setTimeout(() => {
                    const tables = editor.dom.select('table');
                    tables.forEach(table => {
                        const width = editor.dom.getStyle(table, 'width', true);
                        if (parseInt(width) > 100) {
                            editor.dom.setStyle(table, 'width', '100%');
                        }
                    });
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Using ´´´max-width: 100%´´´ was the way I already solved it. But I would like to disable the possibility to enter a value greather than 100% in the input-field when the table is created.

Comment: Which kind of input field is it ?

Comment: I have tried to clarify in the question.